# Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'. (This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

when I created a very basic flutter app and ran it for the first time, it works perfectly, and when I try to add some dependencies in my pubspec.yaml file I get no errors in my project but when I run the app by 'flutter run' I get stuck in

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...            
(This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)
```

and the app has never worked
this is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: myPDFApp  
description: A new Flutter project. 
publish_to: 'none' 
version: 1.0.0+1
environment: 
 sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
   sdk: flutter   
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^18.4.35-beta // this is the dep that I want to add


dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:   
  sdk: flutter 

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Which dependecies did you add? (Could you copy paste your pubspec.yaml + flutter doctor output)?

Comment: did you run `flutter pub get`?

Comment: @GaspardMerten I have tried to add (syncfusion pdf viewer) dependency as I mentioned  above

Comment: @Nailuj29 yes I did

Comment: @NadjiThabet try restarting your computer. Also, do you have a device connected?

Comment: @Nailuj29 yes I have, thanks for your help , I have fixed this problem by upgrade flutter version, and clean my ~/.gradle/caches/

Answer (score 0):

Add an earlier version of the dependencies, and run pub get. This could solve the issue

Comment: unfortunately, I did all that but the problem still happen

Comment: Try another dependency having the same function, like another pdf Viewer. Maybe the error is because of the beta stage.